# How to use latest version of sass gem with compass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, compass-sass

So i'm using ruby2/rails4 and trying to use the latest version of sass gem (currently 3.3.9) and i'm using compass gem to, that have a dependencie (sass 3.2.0)

so when i try to update gem i got it:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (= 4.0.3) ruby depends on
      sass (~> 3.2.0) ruby

    sass (3.3.9)
```

i need the latest version cause sass now have a random() function it is very usefull

Answer (score 1):

Install the current **pre** version of Compass:

```
gem install compass --pre
```

It has a Sass dependency of:

> < 3.5, >= 3.3.0

so it should be compatible with that version of Sass and allow `random()`. See https://rubygems.org/gems/compass/versions/1.0.0.alpha.21 for more on the alpha version of Compass.

Comment: but i'm using gemfile, how to put --pre in gemfile?

Comment: installing this alpha version of compass all my imports of compass extensions stop working:

`ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/border-radius.` 
i think this is cause i removed compass-rails gem(because have dependencie of sass 3.2.0), if i put her in my gemfile i got this warning:

`Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (= 4.0.3) ruby depends on
      sass (~> 3.2.0) ruby

    compass (~> 1.0.0.alpha.21) ruby depends on
      sass (3.3.11)`

i can't find a alpha version of sass-rails